# Blocking SQL queries when crawling

Tags: search, administration, crawling, mirroring

I am facing a problem where my content database has grown very large, and whenever I initiate a crawl, the the crawler executes a very complex SQL query on the content database, and this query blocks all other queries that execute on the content DB. As a result, my sites either hang, or become very slow in loading pages.

How do I solve this problem? Can I use mirroring in some way to resolve this issue?

Is it possible to mirror the content DB, and run the crawl exclusively on the mirrored DB so that the sql performance of my front end servers are not affected?

Comment: When are you initializing the crawl? Is it done off hours?

Comment: How large is "very large"?

Comment: It has around 100K list items, with each list item having 50 to 200 columns.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered splitting the content Databases into smaller chunks?

I see a few benefits for doing this :

1. Crawler performance
2. Page Response Times
3. Reduce App Pool Recycle Times

Since you are talking about Mirroring DB's I am going to take the liberty of thinking that you may have the capability of having multiple SQL Servers. Consider moving content DB across multiple SQL Servers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following options:

1. Run the crawl during off hours
2. Optimize crawl schedule and avoid unnecessary full crawls
3. Use crawl impact rule to mininize the impact of crawl on the web server performance.